# Merge multiple PivotTables for multiple workbooks to create a master PivotTable

Tags: excel, excel-2010, pivot-table, excel-2013, vba

I've found a code that I've (mostly) successfully modified for my use, but am getting an error on the grouping function. I have a folder that has (at present) three workbooks in them.  Each workbook is formatted exactly the same from sheet names to fields within each sheet.  Each workbook has two PivotTables derived from the same unique data source (a third sheet in the workbook).

I need to be able to, in a new workbook, run a script that will allow me to choose the workbooks from the common folder that I want to combine into one master pivot table. My source data looks like this:

(slashes used after the names for each column and after the data in row 2 are only there to differentiate the different columns (12 in total, A to L inclusive))

Row 1 - Line / Sort / Sub-Cat / Part / Para / Page / Deliv / Action / Owner / DueDate / Status / DateComp

Row 2 - 2 / b / Confrnc / 2 / 2.2.1 / 8 / Attend / Attend / John / 23-May-13 / NotStarted / (blank)

Each workbook has a data source sheet set up exactly like this, with multiple rows of data.

Each workbook has a pivot table that compiles:

### ROWS:

1. Sub-Cat;
2. Action;
3. Owner;
4. Status

### COLUMNS:

1. DueDate

### VALUES:

1. Count of Action

I have the following piece of code that I have modified to meet my needs copied and pasted into a new Module in a new workbook (saved in the same folder as my source workbooks):

---

```
Option Explicit


Declare Function SetCurrentDirectoryA Lib "kernel32" (ByVal Path As String) As Long

'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Author: Rob Bovey
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub ChDirNet(Path As String)
    Dim Result As Long
    Result = SetCurrentDirectoryA(Path)
    If Result = 0 Then Err.Raise vbObjectError + 1, "Error changing to new path."
End Sub

'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Procedure : MergeFiles
' Author    : KL
' Date      : 22/08/2010
' Purpose   : Demonstration (http://www.planetaexcel.ru/forum.php?thread_id=18518)
' Comments  : Special thanks to
'             Debra Dalgleish for helping to fix ODBC driver issue
'             Hector Miguel Orozco Diaz for the "DeleteConnections_12" idea
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'
Sub MergeFiles()
    Dim PT As PivotTable
    Dim PC As PivotCache
    Dim arrFiles As Variant
    Dim strSheet As String
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim strCon As String
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long

    strPath = CurDir
    ChDirNet ThisWorkbook.Path

    arrFiles = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Workbooks (*.xlsx), *.xlsx", , , , True)
    strSheet = "Deliverables"

    If Not IsArray(arrFiles) Then Exit Sub

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    If Val(Application.Version) > 11 Then DeleteConnections_12

    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells
    rng.Clear
    For i = 1 To UBound(arrFiles)
        If strSQL = "" Then
            strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [" & strSheet & "$]"
        Else
            strSQL = strSQL & " UNION ALL SELECT * FROM `" & arrFiles(i) & "`.[" & strSheet & "$]"
        End If
    Next i
    strCon = _
        "ODBC;" & _
        "DSN=Excel Files;" & _
        "DBQ=" & arrFiles(1) & ";" & _
        "DefaultDir=" & "" & ";" & _
        "DriverId=790;" & _
        "MaxBufferSize=2048;" & _
        "PageTimeout=5"

    Set PC = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add(SourceType:=xlExternal)

    With PC
        .Connection = strCon
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = strSQL
        Set PT = .CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=rng(6, 1))
    End With

    With PT
        With .PivotFields(1)                             'Sub Category
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 1
        End With
        .AddDataField .PivotFields(8), "DueDate", xlCount 'Action Required
        With .PivotFields(1)                             'Action Required
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 1
        End With
        With .PivotFields(1)                             'Owner
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 1
        End With
        With .PivotFields(2)                             'Status
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 1
        .DataRange.Cells(1).Group _
                Start:=True, _
                End:=True, _
                Periods:=Array(False, False, False, False, True, False, False)
        End With
    End With

    'Clean up
    Set PT = Nothing
    Set PC = Nothing

    ChDirNet strPath
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Sub DeleteConnections_12()
    '   This line won't work and wouldn't be necessary
    '   in the versions older than 2007
    '*****************************************************************************
    On Error Resume Next: ThisWorkbook.Connections(1).Delete: On Error GoTo 0
    '*****************************************************************************
End Sub


Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

End Sub
```

---

When I run the script, I get to Line 92, where I get a run-time error 1004: Cannot group that selection.

```
.DataRange.Cells(1).Group _
                Start:=True, _
                End:=True, _
                Periods:=Array(False, False, False, False, True, False, False)
```

---

For the life of me, I'm lost and cannot find anything anywhere to fix this.

Can anyone make any recommendations or suggestions?

I am still very new at VBA, but not with PivotTables. I am trying to avoid having to manually compile all of the data from the source workbooks into a master and running the PivotTable from there, because the workbooks are owned by three different users and are updated regularly.  I am utilizing an OFFSET formula to name my source data range, and using this as my data source for my PivotTables so they all update at once, and the formula automatically increases the range to include any new rows or columns that have been added to the source data sheet.

I also recognize that just because it works up to the grouping point, that doesn't mean that the variables for the PivotFields are done correctly either - so if someone sees something there too - I'm open to hearing about it!

I am working in Excel 2013 and 2010.

Comment: First tip- your question is too localized. Any of us can't repeat your situation which makes any help difficult. Next, I just checked [`Range.Group` method reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff839808%28v=office.14%29.aspx) and I'm not sure if your field is date or numeric type. I see `Status` comment which seems to be `String` which possibly doesn't match `.Group` method requirements. Please check it, cut your code, add some screen shot for further help.

Comment: Thanks @KazJaw.  My focus has been reassigned at the moment, but I'll be able to take a look at it next week... I'll plug away at chew at it some more and see where I can get with your feedback.  I did try screen prints with the original post, but I don't have enough reputation points yet to post pictures or screen prints!thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

*Transfer from Question what appears to be an answer, or as near as likely to be achieved:*

Here are screen shots of both my data set of what my pivot tables look like derived from each individual workbook's data set, and how I want it to look by running the script:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6env.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/joA34.png]

Looking at @KazJaw comments, I've researched the `Range.Group` and looked at the `Periods` portion. I ended up deleting it completely and ran the script without a problem! Have to manually adjust the Field Lists and formatting, but that's the easy part compared with pulling the actual data as it is always and ever changing.